# while speaking using headphones how to stop sending internal sound with my voice?

Tags: sound, headphones

While speaking on TeamViewer or anything else using headphones I usually play sound in the background.

The problem is that the whoever I'm speaking can hear the background sound.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using skype to talk to them. Make sure you disable your sound in teamviewer. In ur settings, on your computer disable the sound from teamwiever.

If you are using TeamViewer to talk to another person, you shouldn't be able to hear them.

Comment: the thing is I can`t find that option I want ubuntu to take sound only from speakers not from internal system

Comment: same question here.

Comment: @AbdulrhmanDjoukhadar did you find any solution?